# How to split a tuple and save it to a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, tuples

I have a list of tuples like this:

```
a=[('A7855', 'item1', 'item2'),('A7856', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5')]
```

and I want to save that list to a dataframe, like this:

```
No    ID     itemNum
1     A7855  item1
2            item2
3     A7856  item3
4            item4
5            item5
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension with flattening and loop all values without first for list of tuples, then pass it to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
b = [(x[0], y) for x in a for y in x[1:]]
df = pd.DataFrame(b, columns=['ID','itemNum'])
print (df)
      ID itemNum
0  A7855   item1
1  A7855   item2
2  A7856   item3
3  A7856   item4
4  A7856   item5
```

If need only first values for `ID` column add `if-else` statement with enumerate for counter of lists:

```
b = [(x[0], y) if i == 0 
               else ('', y) 
               for x in a for i, y in enumerate(x[1:])]
df = pd.DataFrame(b, columns=['ID','itemNum'])
print (df)
      ID itemNum
0  A7855   item1
1          item2
2  A7856   item3
3          item4
4          item5
```

And if need new column `No` add [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) for add first new column with index values + 1:

```
df.insert(0, 'No', df.index + 1)
print (df)
   No     ID itemNum
0   1  A7855   item1
1   2          item2
2   3  A7856   item3
3   4          item4
4   5          item5
```

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.melt.html) here::

```
df=(pd.DataFrame(a).melt(0,value_name='itemNum').
drop('variable',1).dropna().sort_values(0).rename(columns={0:'ID'}).reset_index(drop=True))
print(df)
```

---

```
      ID itemNum
0  A7855   item1
1  A7855   item2
2  A7856   item3
3  A7856   item4
4  A7856   item5
```

---

To match you exact requirement, do on `df`:

```
df.loc[df.duplicated('ID'),'ID']=''
df.insert(0,'No',range(1,len(df)+1))
print(df)
```

---

```
   No     ID itemNum
0   1  A7855   item1
1   2          item2
2   3  A7856   item3
3   4          item4
4   5          item5
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you use multiple variable assignment. All variables in the tuple after the first one go into "itemnum".

```
data=[('A7855', 'item1', 'item2'),('A7856', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5')]
rows = []
ids = set()
for idx, *itemnum in data:
    for i in itemnum:
        if idx in ids:
            idx = ''
        rows.append((idx, i))
        ids.add(idx)
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['ID','itemNum'])
df.index = [i+1 for i in df.index]
```

My output:

```
      ID itemNum
1  A7855   item1
2          item2
3  A7856   item3
4          item4
5          item5
```